# NullReferenceException changing the logic within the statement

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, logical-operators

I have the following piece of code.

```
(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(billInfo.BillingMethod) || (!billInfo.BillingMethod.Equals(bill) && bill != null)
```

I understand that I'm getting a null reference exception because more than likely its comparing a null value within the equals method. However I'm confused on how to change the logic so I still end up with the same result without using a method.

Comment: You're checking if bill is null last?  Use the debugger to find out what is actually null when the exception is thrown.

Comment: Shouldn't you use "and" instead of "or"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check everything that could be null. I just assume billInfo could be null too. Also The order of the statements is important here.

```
(billInfo != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(billInfo.BillingMethod) || (bill != null && !billInfo.BillingMethod?.Equals(bill))
```

Comment: Sorry I should have added the full line

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(billInfo.BillingMethod) || (billCheck.BillingMethod != null && (!(billInfo.BillingMethod.Equals(billCheck.BillingMethod)))))

Answer (score 0):

`NullReferenceException` can occur if `billInfo` or `BillingMethod` is null. So first checking for `billInfo` not equal to null, then check for other conditions. Also, the condition after the `||` is the other way around. As there is no point of checking not null if the first statement is failed.

Try this instead:

```
 if(billInfo != null && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(billInfo.BillingMethod) ||
                        (bill != null && !billInfo.BillingMethod.Equals(bill)))
 {
      // Your code here
 }
```

Comment: Would you please explain why your solution solves the problem?

Comment: NullReferenceException  can occur if 'billInfo' is null. Only if it is not null, then

Comment: NullReferenceException  can occur if 'billInfo'  or 'BillingMethod' is null.   So first checking for 'billInfo' not equal to null, then checking for other conditions. Also the condition after the '||' is otherway around..  as there is no point of checking  not null if the first statement is failed